# How to make a synchronous http get in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, https, synchronization

I have a code that calls an API based on values inside a txt file.
Out of each API call, the code extracts some information from the response JSON and constructs a csv.
I have gotten my code to work by overwriting the csv each time I finish an HTTP get call to the API. However, I would prefer to only write the csv once for efficiency's sake. My current code is something like this...

```
const fs = require("fs");
const https = require("https");
var text = ""
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) reject(error);
    issns = data.split(/\r?\n/)
    getPolicies(issns);
});

function getPolicies(issns){
    for (let i = 0; i<issns.length; i++){
        url = "some_api_url" + issns[i]
        https.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                constructCSV(issns[i], data)
            });
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
    }
}
function constructCSV (issn, data){
    // code to get some data from the json in parameter "data"
    // ...
    // ...
    saveOutput()            
}
function saveOutput(){
    fs.writeFileSync(output_file_dir, text);
}
```

As mentioned I would prefer to only call saveOutput() once, if possible right after calling getPolicies(). However that results in a blank csv file since get policies uses the asynchronous http get.

If anyone could help I would be very thankful!

Comment: I'd recommend to use something like `axios` or `got` to woork with http(s)-requests and, of course, to use `async/await` to achieve a straight-forward and synchronous-like looking code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you don't really need synchronous request, but detecting when all the requests are done.

A simple solution would be to track the last request, and then pass it as parameter to `constructCSV`, which would then call `saveOutput` upon all requests are done flag:

```
// send last request flag
constructCSV(issns[i], data, i+1==issns.length)

//...

// write on the last request flag
function constructCSV (issn, data, done){
    // code to get some data from the json in parameter "data"
    // ...
    // ...
    if(done) saveOutput()            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are asynchronous in nature and it is against the spirit of Node.js to block its single thread while waiting for such a request to finish. Luckily, this is not necessary.

You don't show us how `text` is filled with data, but since you cannot control in which order your requests finish, your code is likely to give unpredictable results.

You should use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to execute all requests in parallel and `Promise.all` to detect when all have finished:

```js
const requests = [];
for (let i = 0; i<issns.length; i++) {
  url = "some_api_url" + issns[i];
  requests.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    https.get(url, (resp) => {
      ...
      resp.on('end', () => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        resolve(data);
      });
    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
      reject(err);
    });
  }));
}
Promise.all(requests).then(function(csvData) {
  const csvContent = csvData.join("\n");
  fs.writeFileSync(output_file_dir, csvContent);
});
```

`csvData` is an array with the `data` of the individual requests in the same order in which you *created* the promises, regardless of the order in which they resolved.